# ORA00933: SQL command not properly ended in Crystal Report

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

I wrote an SQL command via Crystal Reports and I have an error that says my command is not properly ended. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
SELECT SUM(Orders) AS TotalOrders
FROM ORDERS
WHERE ORDER_DATE >= '{?StartDate}' AND 
ORDER_DATE <='{?EndDate}'
```

Comment: Perhaps you need a `;` at the end?

Comment: From what you've posted, the syntax looks fine. Semi colon should not be needed. To help troubleshoot, I recommend commenting out or removing the entire where clause and see if the report runs. If that works, then add in only the StartDate and see if things run. Make sure you are passing in a properly formatted date. Also, which database is this running against?

Comment: @jarlh: adding ; didn't work

Comment: @DouglasTimms : I removed WHERE, then added only StartDate , finally EndDate, and it worked!! thanks ! it is exactly the same SQL as I have posted as before. weird but it worked :) i am running against Oracle ? i am not sure if that is the right answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `'` for parameters

```
SELECT SUM(Orders) AS TotalOrders
FROM ORDERS
WHERE ORDER_DATE >= {?StartDate} AND 
ORDER_DATE <={?EndDate}
```

Comment: Hmm, I always use single quotes around my parameters, even date parameters. I guess it depends on how the information is being passed into the report.

Comment: it works now. I tried removing the where clause then adding one parameter at a time. finally it worked . without the single quotes.

Comment: You can accept it as answer...if its working so that others can use